# How can I set the value variable in finally with VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Hi I have an axios function which I need to verifiy a value and it will return to me 1 or 0, it works but the thing is that I need to set this value in the finally part of the axios function my code is this one:

```
axios.post('/api/employee/verify?api_token='+App.apiToken, formData, config)
      .then(function (response) {
         currentObj.success = response.data.success;
         this.$set(this.form, 'search_data', response.data.success);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
.finally(() => {
   if(currentObj.success == 1) {
      this.$awn.success("El colaborador ha trabajado con nosotros", {labels: {success: "Encontrado"}});
      this.$router.push('/employee/confirm');
  } else {
      this.$awn.alert("El colaborador no ha trabajado con nosotros", {labels: {success: "No Encontrado"}});
      this.$router.push('/employee/create');
  }
                        
  this.loading = false;
 });
```

How you can see there is a .finally part of the axios function and it has currentObj.success the thing is that it says that is undefined but it is not, I wonder how can I set the value that I receive in .finally of the axios function? Thanks

Comment: You can't guarantee that there was no error and so that currentObj.success was set . The only piece that surely belongs to finally is `this.loading = false`. It's not relevant to the problem, but this `.then(function (response) {` is a mistake, it should be an arrow

Answer (score 1):

`finally()` is usually used to perform some actions whenever the Axios request is successful or not. You should face this in another way.

If you are developing your own API the best choice here is to return a `404` or any relevant `error` code if no employee was found/verified. Therefore your vue js could be like

```
axios.post('/api/employee/verify?api_token='+App.apiToken, formData, config)
    .then((response) => {
        this.$set(this.form, 'search_data', response.data.success)
        this.$awn.success("El colaborador ha trabajado con nosotros", {labels: {success: "Encontrado"}})
        this.$router.push('/employee/confirm')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        this.$awn.alert("El colaborador no ha trabajado con nosotros", {labels: {success: "No Encontrado"}})
        this.$router.push('/employee/create')
    })
    .finally(() => {                                
        this.loading = false
    })
```

If changing your API response is not an option for you, then just move your `finally` code withing your `then()` promise

```
axios.post('/api/employee/verify?api_token='+App.apiToken, formData, config)
    .then((response) => {
        currentObj.success = response.data.success
        this.$set(this.form, 'search_data', response.data.success)

        if(currentObj.success == 1) {
            this.$awn.success("El colaborador ha trabajado con nosotros", {labels: {success: "Encontrado"}})
            this.$router.push('/employee/confirm')
        } else {
            this.$awn.alert("El colaborador no ha trabajado con nosotros", {labels: {success: "No Encontrado"}})
            this.$router.push('/employee/create')
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    .finally(() => {                                
        this.loading = false
    })
```